# How to force Feeds to import content? (Feeds too lazy to import every minute)

Tags: feeds

I've setup Feeds to import content every minutes. All settings was fine.
Feed source contains only 1 rss item, and it changed every 1 or 2 minutes.

When I manually click "Import" tab, it will import nicely. But in many times, Feeds too lazy to import it.

By using cron, Is there any way I can force Feeds to import?

Comment: I would also like to know this. I don't know if lazy is the right word but I would like to import more often than cron runs, I'm not gonna run Cron every other minute...

Comment: @Karl If you made that its own question, I'd happily answer it, but using cron.php vs. not doing so are different enough that they really shouldn't be lumped together.

Comment: @Karl you can use the [Elysia Cron module](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) to split up your Cron tasks so you could run some every minute and others at different intervals

Comment: If the source has PubSubHubbub support, that's your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Check the minimum refresh period in your feeds setting; feeds will not import anything if the last import is more recent than that setting.

Answer (score 1):

In the Feeds settings page, in the settings section, check the option 'Skip hash check' -Force update of items even if item source data did not change.

This will prevent the importer from checking for any change, and import every time.

I would also check that the import task is quick enough to happen every minute. Imports can take several minutes, and re-calling the import by the cron every minute may disrupt this.

Comment: +1. Also, don't confuse with the GUID setting. GUID thing is to prevent duplicate items. Hash check is to make imports faster.

Answer (score 0):

Create drush command and add it in your crontab file on the server.